# How to convert a struct tm to DateTime in c++/cli

Tags: datetime, time, c++-cli

I have a variable in c++/CLI whch holds time as a struct tm. I need to convert it to managed DateTime. How can I do this?

```
 struct tm t=GetTime();
 DateTime time= ConvertToDateTime(t);
```

In the above code, how can I implement Convert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be:

```
struct tm t = GetTime();
// not sure of syntax here, calling the constructor from C++,
// but I think you get the idea.
DateTime time = DateTime(t.tm_year+1900, t.tm_mon+1, t.tm_day, t.tm_hour, t.tm_min, t.tm_sec);
```

Comment: Yes.  The Kind matters too, it is ambiguous for *tm* since it depends on how it as obtained.